# Exclude a string via a dropdownlist

Tags: laravel

I have a table named `Student` with 1 field which is `Level` with 3 items:

`level1, level2, leve3`.

In my form, if the user selects `level3` , an error message must appear.

I have tried this but it's not correct...

**Edit** 
Undefined variable: student

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    { 
    $student = Student::select('level')->where("id", "=", $student->level)->first();

      if($student->level != "level3") {
          return redirect()->route('students.index')
            ->with('error', 'This type of level is not allowed to you!');
       }`
```

Comment: `$student` is a `Collection` of `Student` models; `$student->level` will not return anything. You need to do this in a loop, or change `->get()` to `->first()`. One point of clarification; what's the reasoning behind `->where("id", "=", $request->level);`? Will `level1` ever match an `id` column value? Also, can't you just check `if($request->level != "level3")`? Why do you need to query `Student`?

Comment: @Tim Lewis: Thank you for your help. It's a exercice to ameliore my learning..
I have an error message -> Trying to get property 'level' of non-object.
It's this line `if($request->level != "level3")`, I don't understand... 

`$request = Student::select('level')->where("id", "=", $request->level)->first();
        if($request->level != "level3") {
             return redirect()->route('students.index')
                    ->with('error', 'This type of level is not allowed to you!');
            }`

Comment: You're overriding `$request`: `$request = Student::(...)` That should be `$student = Student::(...);`

Comment: @Tim Lewis, I have an error message `Undefined variable: student`... For information I have edited my first message with your code.

Comment: Well yeah... Now you're doing `$student = Student::where("id", "=", $student->level)->first();` That should be `$id`... You really need to be aware of the code you're writing; this is basic. You can't use the variable in the same declaration as the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't yet have a student object to query on.  Thus, when you ask to find all students in the database who have a level that matches the `$student->level`, it will always fail with an undefined variable.  You don't *have* a `$student` object yet to pull the level from it.  I assume that's the reason you are running the query in the first place: to get all students at the level requested from the form (via `$request`).

If you want to get all students in the database with the level as sent from the form, you can query like this:

```
 $students = Student::where("level", $request->get('level'))->get();
```

This will return a collection of students at whatever level got sent through the `$request` object into this method.

If you just want any single student of that level (doesn't matter which one, as long as his level is whatever $request has sent from the form), you can use this line:

```
$student = Student::where("level", $request->get('level'))->first();
```

This will give you one single student object.

I'm not sure if you wanted to find the student by level, or by id, since your parameters for the update method included both:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){...}
```

If you were looking for a specific student just by id, you can use:

```
$student = Student::find($id);
```

This will give you the exact student you were looking for based on `id`.  Nothing else matters (not level) - it is an exact match to that one student based on `id`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your relevant explanations, I will take notes. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code i guess there was mistake

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{ 
    $student = Student::select('level')->where("id", "=",$id)->first(); // in this line you have passed  $student->level insted of $id

      if($student && $student->level != "level3") { // here also changes
          return redirect()->route('students.index')
            ->with('error', 'This type of level is not allowed to you!');
      }else{
        return redirect()->back();
     }
}
```